# Running expect in systemd unit causes sh syntax error

Tags: systemd, vpn, expect

I am trying to automate the process of connecting to my VPN (SonicWall NetExtender) from my Linux machine by using a `systemd` unit to call an `expect` script that supplies the login credentials to the VPN client. Here are the files:

`netextender.service`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=SonicWall NetExtender VPN
PartOf=systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/.netExtender
## environment file spec:
# DOMAIN=
# HOSTNAME=
# PASSWORD=
# TOTP_SEED=
# USERNAME=

ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/pkill -9 netExtender || true'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/netextender.expect

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

`netextender.expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

exp_internal 0
set timeout -1
set TOTP_CODE [exec totpgen $env(TOTP_SEED)]
spawn netExtender --dns-only-local --ppp-async --vpntype=wireguard "$env(HOSTNAME)"
expect {
  "*\nUser: " {
    send -- "$env(USERNAME)\n"
    exp_continue
  } "*\nPassword: " {
    send -- "$env(PASSWORD)\n"
    exp_continue
  } "*\nDomain: " {
    send -- "$env(DOMAIN)\n"
    exp_continue
  } "*\nDo you want to proceed? (Y:Yes, N:No, V:View Certificate)" {
    send -- "y\n"
    exp_continue
  } "*\nOne Time Password: " {
    send -- "$TOTP_CODE\n"
  }
}
interact
```

The `expect` script successfully starts the VPN client when called from an interactive shell, but fails with the following error when called from `systemd`:

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 1: `mkdir -p (null)/.netExtenderCerts/PUB_CERT'
spawn_id: spawn id exp3 not open
while executing
interact"
file "/usr/local/bin/netextender.expect" line 24)
netextender.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

This perplexes me, as I can't figure out why `sh` is involved at all, much less why it works for me directly but not via `systemd`. According to `file`, `netExtender` is a regular binary executable:

`/usr/bin/netExtender: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5c2daed3c6e1e9f7b7e8ec62f466e6967618c68f, stripped`

Have you any advice for an `expect` novice to get this working?

Comment: Does `HOSTNAME` exists in the environment for systemd? Inspect the environment with `parray env`. You might need to `[exec hostname]` instead.

Comment: @glennjackman that variable is provided by the environment file, referenced by and whose spec is in the systemd unit, but not shown here for privacy/security reasons.

Comment: netExtender is failing (for some reason). You can handle the error by adding an `eof` case to the `expect` command. But you'll need to dig into why netExtender is failing.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved @MrDrMcCoy?